# Friend Follow/Unfollow Table Structure #MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

At the moment this current function stands as followed:

*userFriends*

```
friend_iD | friend_One | friend_Two | Role |

friend_iD : int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT.
friend_One: int(11).
friend_Two: int(11).
Role: VARCHAR(5).
```

Once I first register, the following will be inserted into the userFriends table (In this example I will be using iD 2 for myself).

```
friend_iD | friend_One | friend_Two | Role |
    15          NULL         NULL       me
```

If I'm visiting John's profile who's iD is **1**, and I click the **[Follow]** button, the following is inserted into userFriends table columns.

```
friend_iD | friend_One | friend_Two | Role |
    20            2           1         fri

iD 1 : John
iD 2 : Gabby(Myself)
```

Now it means that I'm friend_One with the iD of 2 is following John who has the iD of 1.

```
Gabby[2] > John[1]
```

**1. Is this a good table structure for a follow system?**

**2. If it isn't, what could I improve or chance to make it faster or
    better, I doubt it would have any performance trouble with such a
    simple function.**

Answer (score 1):

```
Once I first register, the following will be inserted into the userFriends table 
(In this example I will be using iD 2 for myself).
```

You need a separate table for user such as

```
users
user_id | username | password | active | etc (email and another info)
```

and then you need to create `follow` table like your design

```
follow
friend_id | follower_user_id | followed_user_id
```

i didnt got what use of Role field in your design. Just add it if you need it

Comment: That's what I've currently have, I'm just trying to find out if there's a better way of having a follow/unfollow table structure that's more for performance.

Comment: i think table structure isnt the problem, if you have performance issue maybe you can do performance tuning for mysql,create indexes, query optimazion, etc

Comment: What should we do when user unfollow. remove row from table or need to maintain status for that?